# image cropping on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've had an issue trying to crop an image in unity. I looked up various methods of tryin to accomplish this but am still pretty new to C# coding. My code is below.

My idea is to use Rectangle information as my cropping tool of the image but it only crops the lower left corner. The goal is to crop a bulk of images and save them back to the folder.

```
public class ImageCropper : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Sprite oldImage;
    [SerializeField] GameObject newSize;
    //Select a Texture in the Inspector to change to
    Texture2D sourceTexture;
    RectTransform sourceRect;
    private string folder = "**FILEPATH**";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Change the Texture to be the one you define in the Inspector
        sourceTexture = oldImage.texture;
        sourceRect = newSize.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        int x = Mathf.FloorToInt(sourceRect.position.x);
        int y = Mathf.FloorToInt(sourceRect.position.y);
        int width = Mathf.FloorToInt(sourceRect.rect.width);
        int height = Mathf.FloorToInt(sourceRect.rect.height);

        /*Debug.Log(sourceRect.position.x + " " + sourceRect.position.y + " " + sourceRect.rect.width + " " + sourceRect.rect.height);
        Debug.Log(x + " " + y + " " + width + " " + height);*/

        Color[] pix = sourceTexture.GetPixels();
        Texture2D newImage = new Texture2D(width, height);
        newImage.SetPixels(pix);
        newImage.Apply();


        byte[] bytes = newImage.EncodeToPNG();

        File.WriteAllBytes(folder + "/soldier1.png", bytes);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There is an open source image crop library for unity on github in  which you can find the code of cropping. Here is link [link](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityImageCropper)

Comment: Please phrase your question as an explicit question. for example "can somebody suggest how i might change my code or suggest alternative way to achieve this intent" to make it clear what you are asking, also you do not explain what issue you experience

Answer (score 0):

[Texture2D.GetPixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) has an overload that lets you retrieve only a subset of the pixels.

```
Texture2D Crop(Texture2D sourceTexture, RectTransform cropRectTransform)
{
    var cropRect = new RectInt
    (
        Mathf.FloorToInt(cropRectTransform.position.x),
        Mathf.FloorToInt(cropRectTransform.position.y),
        Mathf.FloorToInt(cropRectTransform.rect.width),
        Mathf.FloorToInt(cropRectTransform.rect.height)
    );

    var newPixels = sourceTexture.GetPixels(cropRect.x, cropRect.y, cropRect.width, cropRect.height);
    var newTexture = new Texture2D(cropRect.width, cropRect.height);
    newTexture.SetPixels(newPixels);
    newTexture.Apply();
    return newTexture;
}
```

Comment: What is the width and height in the newTexture from?

Comment: Ah sorry, it's supposed to be cropRect.width and cropRect.height. I'll edit the answer.